# Travelling to Bali from India with a layover in Kuala Lumpur. Visa requirement and time required to switch flights?

Tags: visas, india, transit-visas, layovers, kuala-lumpur

I am travelling to Bali from India. My travel is on the same Malaysia Airlines ticket, under the same PNR.

On the onward journey, there is a 15-hour layover before my next flight. Is it a good option to go out, roam around the city and come back? Will I need a visa for this?

Or what are the options inside the airport to kill time?

My return journey to India from Bali is also with Malaysia Airlines under 
 the same PNR. There is a 1-hour layover in this case. Will this be enough to catch my next flight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [an eVisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#eVisa). This is available online, as the name indicates. Fifteen hours is a lot of time to wait in KLIA. You can take the train between the airport and the downtown train station.

If Malaysia Airlines sold you the ticket as is, then they think you can do the connection on the way back. One hour is actually plenty of time, if both flights are in the same terminal (as they should be, since it's all KL).